# Что должно быть, если вызвать async-функцию без await?

Tags: python, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

Разбираюсь с написанием кода с новыми **async**/**await** возможностями. Мне не совсем понятен следующий нюанс. Предположим есть async-функция f1() и что если мы возьмем и вызовем эту функцию в функции f2() без **await** ?

```
async f1():
  # do something
  pass

f2():
  # await f1()
  f1() # without await
  pass
```

Что должно быть в этом случае? Корректно ли такое использование async-f1 функции?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, `f1()` вернёт coroutine, который типа как generator, только не generator (хз почему), и пока к этому coroutine не обратятся за результатом, никакой код выполнен не будет. Теоретически можно сделать что-то вроде `foo = f1(); await foo` и всё будет работать и f1 запускаться в строчке с await, только по-моему нафиг не надо)

Comment: ну и какие у вас сложности с тем чтобы написать простейший Рабочий пример и Посмотреть что вернет f1()? :)  Уверяю, вопрос разу отпадет

Comment: @vadimvaduxa это не проблема, проблема посмотреть, что происходит в нутрях перед этим самым возвращением и насколько безопасно игнорировать возвращаемое значение. Этого и я точно не знаю)

Comment: вы даже не попытались, иначе уже бы знали ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Во многих случаях, чтобы получить ответ на свой вопрос, достаточно написать немножко кода и посмотреть что происходит

`С await`:

```
import asyncio

async def f1(a):
    '''Предположим есть async-функция f1()'''
    print("set", a)
    return a + 1

async def f2(a):
    '''если мы возьмем и вызовем эту функцию в функции f2() C await'''
    print("get", a)
    b = await f1(a + 1)
    print('res', b)
    return b

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
b = loop.run_until_complete(f2(a=1))
print(b)

# get 1
# set 2
# res 3
# 3
```

`Без await`:

```
import asyncio

async def f1(a):
    '''Предположим есть async-функция f1()'''
    print("set", a)
    return a + 1

async def f2(a):
    '''если мы возьмем и вызовем эту функцию в функции f2() Без await'''
    print("get", a)
    b = f1(a + 1)
    print('res', b)
    return b

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
b = loop.run_until_complete(f2(a=1))
b = loop.run_until_complete(b)
print(b)

# get 1
# res <coroutine object set_ at 0x02FB4F90>
# set 2
# 3
```